# Odd 'Program name' when installing signed msi installer

Tags: installation, windows-installer

I'm running into the following issue after signin an MSI installer. I'm using signtool.exe and the msi file signs OK however when I test it, the UAC confirmation dialog which shows my company's name shows a 'Program name:' of 55847.msi, rather than the name of my setup file. E.g. Setup1.msi
Does any one know how to 'fix' this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 38):

Add `/d` option to the command line of `signtool.exe` when signing your MSI:

```
signtool.exe /d "Your Software Name"
```

UAC confirmation dialog will show *Your Software Name* as the Program name.

Comment: Thanks!!! (I'd 'read the manual' but there are just too many manuals :)

Answer (score 1):

If you Authenticode-sign your .msi package, Windows will show that as the name. Otherwise, you get MSI's temporary copy of it, which has a random name.

Comment: I assume that means that for unsigned packages the full path to the locally cached database is always shown? [This issue came up again today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079546/is-it-possible-to-define-a-windows-installer-uninstaller-filename/48080788). Is there anything in the WiX MSI that can affect what is shown apart from the signature? Not that important, just curious.