# MSI created with WiX has admin privileges problem

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have created an installer with WIX that is an Add-In for Office. To install it you need administrator privileges. The problem is that when the privileges  window comes out (the Windows window) the name of the file that appears is "47cf119c.msi". (The same happens to uninstall it)

ScreenShot (sorry it's in spanish)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kaxfb.png

I want that there appears "MyInstaller.msi" not "47cf119c.msi"

My wix code

````
<Product Id="*" Name="Word Plugin" Language="1033" Version="4.0.0.0" Manufacturer="St"
         UpgradeCode="fd039382-2310-4101-9419-c626249d2c95">

<Package InstallerVersion="208" Compressed="yes" InstallPrivileges="elevated" AdminImage="yes"
         InstallScope="perMachine" />```
````

Comment: [Is this screenshot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51204163/129130) in line with what you see? You need a certificate to sign your MSI. Please read the linked answer.

Comment: @SteinÅsmul no, that's not what I see. My .msi is signed, the problem is the Admin Privilage request, because appears "47cf119c.msi" not "MyInstaller.msi"

Comment: A screenshot please.

Comment: @SteinÅsmul I added to the question, sorry because it's in spanish it says "Do you want to allow this application to make changes in your computer?"

Comment: I wonder what kind of certificate was used to sign the MSI. Did you sign it yourself? [Like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6869564/129130)?

Comment: @SteinÅsmul yes, and I have not problem with another installers signed with this certificate

Comment: I would try on another computer to verify first of all. Next I would sign a vanilla MSI built from just minimal changes in the default WiX project. I see the language attribute is missing? Maybe try to keep it English and try signing a vanilla MSI? [Just create a vanilla test project like this (changes indicated in bottom markup will do - the inline comments)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47972615/129130).