# Windows Installer Unknown Publisher

Tags: windows-installer

I am creating a project and I did an installer for windows. When I click the installer, I encounter with a warning which is "that do you want to allow this app from unknown publisher to make changes to your device". Probably the reason of it security reasons. I do not want to see it when I install my program. How can I do it? Thanks

Comment: You need to sign the MSI with a digital certificate. [Some information on Microsoft SmartScreen and digital certificates here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50407893/129130). As far as I know you need an [EV-code signing certificate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Validation_Certificate). EV => "Extended Validation".

Comment: [Here is one more link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51204163/installshield-custom-dialogue-installer), please check it.

Comment: @SteinÅsmul I had get a certificate and I signed my executable with this certificate. Now, when I try to install my app, I see myselft as publisher instead of unknown. Thank you so much.

Comment: Great, I added the answer below so you can accept it - for others who see this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to sign the MSI with a digital certificate. [**Some information on Microsoft SmartScreen and digital certificates here**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50407893/129130).

As far as I know **you need an [EV-code signing certificate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Validation_Certificate)**. EV => "Extended Validation".

---

***Signing Process***: [Odd 'Program name' when installing signed msi installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6863137/odd-program-name-when-installing-signed-msi-installer/6869564#6869564)

```
signtool.exe /d "Your Software Name"
```

Many MSI tools incorporate this process inside their tools's GUI (it happens auto-magically when you point to the certificate).

Actual command line used by Latif Uluman (from comments):

```
signtool sign /debug /fd SHA256 /tr timestamp.globalsign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll /f certificatepath /p certificateprivatekey executablepath
```

---

***Links:***

- [On digital signing and SmartScreen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50414337/129130)
- [Installshield Custom Dialogue Installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51204163/installshield-custom-dialogue-installer)
- [What is causing to show Publisher to unknown on UAC despite signing exe using signtool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70035042/what-is-causing-to-show-publisher-to-unknown-on-uac-despite-signing-exe-using-si/70038018#70038018)

Comment: I followed the method of @Stein. Additionally I added some extra options. The final command of me is:  signtool sign /debug  /fd SHA256 /tr http://timestamp.globalsign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll  /f certificatepath /p certificateprivatekey executablepath

Comment: Great, I updated the answer. Thanks for taking the time to add that detail.