# UAC Window application name

Tags: wix, windows-installer, uac

I have a application that uses Wix for its installer.
I'd like to understand where the UAC window takes its app name from, I am having an old name where the UAC window appears does not correspond with current productname defined in Wix.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Digital Signature***: It looks like your MSI is signed with a code-signing certificate?

*"If you Authenticode-sign your .msi package, Windows will show that as the name. Otherwise, you get MSI's temporary copy of it, which has a [random name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51204163/129130)."* - [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6865592/129130).

***Signtool.exe***: You need to modify your **`signtool.exe`** parameters:
[Odd 'Program name' when installing signed msi installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6863137/odd-program-name-when-installing-signed-msi-installer/6869564#6869564)

Some old answers with comments discussing **`signtool.exe`** parameters:

- [What is causing to show Publisher to unknown on UAC despite signing exe using signtool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70035042/what-is-causing-to-show-publisher-to-unknown-on-uac-despite-signing-exe-using-si/70038018#70038018)
- [Windows Installer Unknown Publisher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64065182/windows-installer-unknown-publisher/64092217#64092217)

---

***Links on Digital Signing***:

- [Installshield Custom Dialogue Installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51204163/installshield-custom-dialogue-installer/51209972#51209972)
- [How to add publisher in Installshield 2018](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50407893/how-to-add-publisher-in-installshield-2018/50414337#50414337)

Comment: you it was that, thank you @Stein Åsmul